# DOMContentLoaded fired every time form is submit

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome extension, which has a very simple form.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="status"></div>
    <form id="typeForm">
        Type: <input id="typeInput" type="text" name="type"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

And popup.js has the following:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById('status').textContent = 'Enter Type';
    document.getElementById('typeForm').removeEventListener('submit', typeFormDidSubmit);
    document.getElementById('typeForm').addEventListener('submit', typeFormDidSubmit);
});

function typeFormDidSubmit() {
    var type = document.getElementById('typeInput').textContent;
    if (type && type.length > 0) {
        document.getElementById('status').textContent = 'Processing...';
        startProcessing();
    } else {
        document.getElementById('status').textContent = 'Type cannot be empty';
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that regardless of what I type into the form, be it empty or some other characters, as soon as typeFormDidSubmit is called, DOMContentLoaded is triggered as well, flashing the status message back to "Enter Type".  I thought DOMContentLoaded is only called once per page.

Is there anything I can do to only call the first set of commands just once when the page loads?

Comment: form submit loads the page specified by `<form action` attribute - this attribute defaults to the current page - so, you are effectively reloading the page when you hit submit - you want to run the `preventDefault` method of the submit `event`

Comment: Thanks @JaromandaX, then it seems that form isn't what I should use, as I want to trigger local JS script.  I should probably use TextArea + button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the comment by @Jaromanda X and reading up on submit forms, it seems that form is used to POST requests with some data.
Since I want to call a local JS function, I should use TextArea + Button.

Comment: Our you can preventDefault on submit.